# AngularJS. ng-show. Show html after data was loaded into $scope

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-route

It is needed to display html template after data will be inserted into $scope. 
Code is below. It's work.

```
var b2buiDemo = angular.module('b2buiDemo', [...]);

b2buiDemo.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/exthtlcd', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/exthtlcd-list.html',
        controller: 'ExternalHotelCodeListCtrl',
        resolve:{list:function(ExternalHotelCodeRestClient){
          return ExternalHotelCodeRestClient.getPage();
        }}
      }).     
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/exthtlcd'
      });
  }]);

b2buiDemo.run(['$rootScope', function($root) {
  $root.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(e, curr, prev) { 
    if (curr.$$route && curr.$$route.resolve) {
      // Show a loading message until promises aren't resolved
      $root.loadingView = false;
      console.log("HIDE");
    }
  });
  $root.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, curr, prev) { 
    // Hide loading message
    $root.loadingView = true;
    console.log("SHOW");
  });
}]);

var externalHotelCodeCtrls = angular.module('externalHotelCodeCtrls', []);


externalHotelCodeCtrls.controller('ExternalHotelCodeListCtrl',['$scope', 'list', 
  function($scope,list){
    console.log("FILL SCOPE 1");
    $scope.list=list.data;
    console.log("FILL SCOPE 2");
  }]);

var externalHotelCodeRestClientServices = angular.module('externalHotelCodeRestClientServices', []);

externalHotelCodeRestClientServices.factory('ExternalHotelCodeRestClient',['$http','$q',function($http,$q){

    return{
        getPage: function(){
            var promise = $http.get('***');
            promise.success(function(data){
                console.log('SUCCESS');
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            });
            return promise;             
        }
    }
}]);
```

exthtlcd-list.html

```html
<div ng-show='loadingView'>...</div>
```

Looks like everything is fine. Empty template is not displayed.

BUT look to console output:
HIDE >> SUCCESS >> SHOW >> FILL SCOPE 1 >> FILL SCOPE 2

**Looks like html is displayed after promise is resolved, but before data inserted into scope. Is it OK? Is no, how can it be fixed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't bring you any problems, due to the strict two way binding of angularjs. The fact is that when the promise is solved the callback it is called istantly as first thing and the div is displayed.

Beware if you are using double-curly-brackets binding that you can flash something like {{youvar}}. To avoid this problem use ng-bind instead.